# Rake aborted when trying to Git Push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Hi I'm a new Ruby on rails student and currently having a problem Git Pushing to Heroku after implementing Divise.

I'm getting the following error

> ```
> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
>    Running: rake assets:precompile
>    rake aborted!
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/config/environments/production.rb:83: unterminated string meets end of file
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/config/environments/production.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting '}'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:250:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
>    /tmp/build_a1864c40-58f6-4071-bc76-b9fed6b25e64/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in define'
>    Tasks: TOP => environment
>    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>   !
>   !     Precompiling assets failed.
>   !
>   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
> ```

From researching online, it seems like the solution should be putting

```
 #required for Heroku
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in application.rb, but that isn't working for.

Any thoughts?

Here's the Github page

https://github.com/cablecharlz/pinteresting

Thanks in advance,
Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read the error message.

Seems like you having issue "syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting '}'" in 
/config/environments/production.rb

line: 83

Comment: o man thanks i fixed the syntax error.  will read the error messages a bit deeper from now on.